Hide Specific Div class for Specific User Role
I'm looking for a function that can hide the div class #header_aside from all users that are 'Employer'. Is someone able to help me with that? I tried a few different functions online but they haven't worked. Any help appreciated.
Thank you!

Try this...
function hideHeaderAsideForEmployers() {
  const userRole = localStorage.getItem('user_role'); // Try localStorage first
  if (!userRole) {
    // If not found in localStorage, try data attribute on the body tag (assuming it's set)
    userRole = document.body.dataset.userRole;
  }
  if (userRole === 'Employer') {
    const headerAside = document.getElementById('header_aside');
    if (headerAside) {
      headerAside.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

// Call the function on page load
window.addEventListener('load', hideHeaderAsideForEmployers);

hideHeaderAsideForEmployers function:
This function checks if the current user has the role 'Employer'.
It first tries to retrieve the user role from localStorage. This is a common storage mechanism in browsers to store data across page loads.
If the role is not found in localStorage, it attempts to get it from a data-user-role attribute set on the body tag (assuming your theme sets this attribute for logged-in users).
Conditional hiding:
If the user role is confirmed as 'Employer', the function targets the element with the ID header_aside using document.getElementById.
If the element is found, its display style is set to none, effectively hiding it from the view.
Function call:
The hideHeaderAsideForEmployers function is called when the page finishes loading using window.addEventListener('load', ... ). This ensures the DOM is fully loaded before trying to access elements.
